# Asterisk C++ API

Tags: c++, asterisk, telephony

I have seen two Asterisk C++ API:
    *  Astxx: Asterisk C++ API and Utility library. a C++ wrapper for Asterisk enabling developers
    * C++ Asterisk Manager API wrapper. Supports receiving events from the Asterisk server and sending actions to Asterisk.

Did somebody try one of these projects?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ast-cppsock/)

I have used this once and it worked for me